# url rewriting with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I found some question about url rewriting: 
[.htaccess: Problem with URL rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230795/htaccess-problem-with-url-rewriting) or
[.htaccess question - URL-rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357623/htaccess-question-url-rewriting)

i tried their method but doesnt work in my case?
mine look simple:

```
http://example.org.uk/member/home.php?profile --> http://example.org.uk/member/home/profile/
http://example.org.uk/member/home.php?history --> http://example.org.uk/member/home/history/

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^home/([0-9][0-9])/$ /home.php?$1
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+).php$ /home.php?$1 [L]
```

any thougt is appricated? thanks

Comment: Your rules and examples contradict each other. Do you want `home.php?profile` to be mapped to `home/profile` (example) or `home/profile` to be rewritten to `home.php?profile` (rewrite code)?

Comment: @Linus: i want to be mapped to home/profile and remove php ex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your making it a bit complicated, the following should work

```
http://example.org.uk/member/home.php?profile --> http://example.org.uk/member/home/profile/
http://example.org.uk/member/home.php?history --> http://example.org.uk/member/home/history/



RewriteRule ^/member/home/(.*)/ /home.php?$1 [L]
```

or more generally

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /home.php?$3 [L]
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a questionmark after the first argument? I am still learning the RewriteMagic :)

Comment: see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559186/php-rewrite-rules/559193#559193 there doesnt need to be a ? in the above.

Comment: thanks. its kinda work. but i need to change my url to absolute path. 1 more thing. when im on `home/profile/` right! and then when i click link on `home/history` the url become like this `home/home/history` any idea why?

Comment: thats the way urls work, if the url has a leading .. it will go down a directory, if it has a  / it will start from the domain base, if it has neither of these it will add on to current url.  Its important to realise the current url in your case for relative url purposes is http://example.org.uk/member/home/history/  not http://example.org.uk/home.php?history .  Test out the alternatives to see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

In RewriteRule you have "^/([^/]+).php$", but you don't want .php extension in URLs. Remove .php from rewrite rule.
Something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/member/home/.*$ /member/home.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/member/home/([a-zA-z0-9]+)/$ /member/home.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

it will still look for the ".php" therefore you could use

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/$ home.php?$1
```